# What percentage of mangakas are females?

Tags: mangaka

My friend says that most of the manga are written by men.

Is that true? What percentage of mangakas are women?

Answer (score 8):

A recent [survey](https://web.archive.org/web/20230119155324/https://vocesabianime.com/eng/77-of-mangakas-are-women/) conducted by Mannavi in November 2021 found that about 77% of mangakas are female. However, the survey only covered a total of 723 responses, so it may not necessarily reflect reality.

Comment: The last part of that article might also give a hint to a related question [What percentage of hentai manga artists are female?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40590/2516).